# phpexcel download file and save in directory

Tags: save, phpexcel

i am using phpexcel with codeignitor.following code ask for download only. i want that it should also save file in following path

$filename= "kp.xlsx";
$filePath = FCPATH."files/application_download/".$filename;

```
if (file_exists($filePath)) {
             unlink($filePath);
            }
            header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="' . $filename . '"');
            header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel2007');
          $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

if i do this   $objWriter->save($filePath);  then this will save a blank file

Answer (score 0):

Rather than save directly to php://output, save the file to your server and then use the PHP [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) function to stream that file to the browser; but make sure that your webserver user has privileges to write a file to that folder.

```
$objWriter->save($filePath);
readfile($filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to give name by yourself then you can specify as I have specified in `$a`

I want to use filename from where this function is being called so I have also concat that name to the excel file name  and also attached current date to the filename

LogReport is a folder where my files will be downloaded

```
self::$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter(self::$objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $a = 'Log' . self::$filename . date("Y-m-d") . '.xlsx';
        $objWriter->save(__DIR__ . '/LogReport/' . $a);
```